# On closure of open sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be real numbers set and $\tau$ be the usual topology. Let $\sigma=\{U=V\setminus C : V\in\tau$, $C\subset\mathbb{R}$ is countable $\}$.

It is clear that $\sigma$ is a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\tau\subset\sigma$ and so $cl_{\sigma}(U)\subset cl_{\tau}(U)$ for every $U\in\tau$  in which $cl$ is the closure operator. How can we show that $cl_{\tau}(U)=cl_{\sigma}(U)$ for every $U\in\tau$. Any hint or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here's a small hint: The rationals are countable and dense in the usual topology.

Comment: Here is my attempt , let $x\in cl_{\tau}(U)$ and $x\notin cl_{\sigma}(U)$ then for a $V\in\sigma$ such that $x\in V$, $U\cap V=\emptyset$. On the other hand $V=V_{1}\setminus C_{1}$ for some $V_{1}\in\tau$ and $C_{1}$ is countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$. @ChrisEagle

Comment: Since $V_{1}\in\tau$ and $x\in V_{1}$ then there exists a basic open set $(a,b)$ such that $x\in (a,b)\setminus C_{1}\subset V_{1}\setminus C_{1}$. So $U\cap (a,b)\setminus C_{1}=\emptyset$ which is a contradiction because $ (a,b)\setminus C_{1}$ is an open set which is the union of the countably many open sets and contains $x$. Isn’t it a contradiction? @ChrisEagle

Comment: possibly I'm just being slow, but it's not clear to me that $\sigma$ is a topology...

Comment: It’s actually. @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: @ChrisEagle any wrong in my proof? Or? Can you please say more?

Comment: You already said it was a topology - simply repeating that assertion is not very helpful

Comment: I am so sorry. What do you think about my attempt ? @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: Why are you asking that? I've said more or less twice that I'm stuck on the first sentence. just maybe you could explain why it's a topology???

Comment: It is a topology known as “countable complement extension topology” from the book Counterexamples in Topology sir. @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich     Also Henno explains it in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291443/proving-the-countable-complement-extension-topology-defines-a-topology